# Function with Dynamic parameter gives an empty plot

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I have a function which depends on three parameters, and I would like to see how it changes as I vary those.
I created three sliders, used `Dynamic` and what I obtain seems to work, in the sense that indeed the function outputs values which are correct and are updated in real-time if I move the sliders.

The problem is that there is no way for me to plot those values. I tried in many different ways (with `Dynamic` inside or outside, with `Evaluate`): nope. Why can't I plot a function which correctly returns values?

```
{"A", Slider[Dynamic[A]], Dynamic[A*100]}
{"α", Slider[Dynamic[α]], Dynamic[α*100]}
{"β", Slider[Dynamic[β]], Dynamic[β + 1]}
σ[ϵ_] = 
 Dynamic[A*100*(Exp[α*100*ϵ] - 1)/(1 + 
      Exp[(β + 1)*α*100*ϵ])]
σ[.001]
Plot[σ[ϵ], {ϵ, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) is exactly what you are looking for, rather than re-constructing this functionality by hand using `Dynamic`, which is often more challenging to use:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
   A*100*(Exp[α*100*ϵ] - 1)/(1 + Exp[(β + 1)*α*100*ϵ]),
   {ϵ, 0, 1},
   PlotRange -> All
 ],
 {A, 0, 100}, {α, 0, 100}, {β, 0, 1}
]
```

[image]

`Manipulate` is very powerful and flexible, and well-worth getting acquainted with: as you look into its documentation, you will also find examples to set the initial values of the parameters, to label them, and much more.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I thought that Manipulate could be used with a single parameter only. Indeed, this is exactly what I was looking for 

Comment: @gwaedin I'm glad this helps! If you think this answers your question to your satisfaction, consider accepting this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark beside it.